# Group every two items in an array while sharing the endings, like a chain

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have an array like this: `[A, B, C, D, E, F]`
, How can I group them like this:

```
[[A, B], [B, C], [C, D], [D, E], [E, F]]
```

(Notice how every last element is shared with the next group, but with the opposite index.)

I know this ain't a big deal of a problem, but I'm trying to keep it simple and short, maybe with `Array.reduce()` if possible:

```js
arr.reduce(function (rows, key, index) { 
   return (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) 
     : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows;
}, []);
// Output: [[A, B], [C, D], [E, F]]
```

Comment: Note that "simple" and "short" are often *competing* aims rather than *complementary* ones: very short code is often harder to read than more explicit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner solution is

```
arr.map((c, i) => [c, arr[i + 1]]).slice(0, -1)
```

**`SOLUTION 1`**

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/maphttps://) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here to achieve the result

> At current `index` return an array  which will contain current element and next element till `last` element

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const result = arr
    .map((c, i) => (i < arr.length - 1 ? [c, arr[i + 1]] : null))
    .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

**`SOLUTION 2`**

You can also acheve this if you get all array combination and remove last one as:

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const result = arr.map((c, i) => [c, arr[i + 1]]).slice(0, -1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with `reduce` method, you can add the current item and the item after it in an array, and then push this array into the `accumulator` of the reducer method, and before `push` you need to check if the current `item` isn't last `item` in the array.

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
   const nextItem = arr[index + 1]
   nextItem ?? acc.push([item, nextItem])
   return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `nextItem &&` isn't a great check because it will skip all falsy values. Better to look for the end of the array explicitly.

Comment: For this case there will be no false values, because all items are string, Also if you want to prevent this case we can use `??` instead.

Comment: That's true, but writing an answer for a single input seems fragile at best. Even nullish coallescing isn't that robust. Why don't you just check the index (which is actually your intent by your own description *'...check if the current item isn't last item in the array.'*)? `(index < arr.length - 1) && ` (also a string can be falsy).

Comment: This answer is not for single input, the only case that will not cover if the item is nullish, and Yes `(index < arr.length - 1)` will be better, it wasn't in my mind then.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stick to the `reduce()` approach here's another method using `map()` and `slice()`.

```js
const data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const result = data.map((_, i) => (i < data.length - 1 ? data.slice(i, i + 2) : null)).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest will be a standard [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. It happens to also be shorter than many of the `reduce()` answers with no extraneous filters or conditions.

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  result.push([arr[i], arr[i + 1]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop is actually shorter if a little less transparent.

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

let result = [], i = 0;
while (i < arr.length - 1) {
  result.push([arr[i], arr[++i]]);
}

console.log(result);
```